# Python not finding modules

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Even after installing selenium using pip on Python 3.6.3, whenever I try to run a code with `import selenium` I get the message that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`.

I usually use Anaconda Prompt and run my codes in Jupyter notebook, but I made the installation also in regular cmd.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

From your command prompt you can run:

```
$ conda list
```

This will list all of the packages in your environment.

Ensure that your system is running the anaconda *flavor* of python.

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import selenium
```

To ensure the uniformity of package management you could use:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

**Edit**: As you can see the path at which the "Requirement is already satisfied" is not the path in which Anaconda is installed.

You may or may not get a message saying that selenium is already installed. In that case, you may just need to ensure that you are in the conda environmnet—either a virtual conda environment or running right off the anaconda installation.

If you use the Anaconda GUI and you can install packages through this, I would try to do so. The point of virtual environments is to void these issues. I would bet `import`ing selenium at the command prompt works, however, trying to use it within a Jupyter Notebook fails—because it is outside the *environment*, virtual or otherwise.

**Updated**:

Installation and testing of installation:

[windows](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html)

[macos](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/macos.html)

linux - the linux people know what's up.

Comment: Thanks man! But I am still facing the trouble... Btw, unistalled and installed anaconda once again, but now when I search for it in my PC, there are two instances of the same program. Also, one of them shows a line with `(base) C:\Users\Usuário>` and when I try to input some command in it, nothing happens...

Comment: This `base` problem is exactly what I was trying to solve... I don't know where it came from

Comment: Getting the result `conda is not recognized as internal or external command.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172320/discussion-between-ericd34n-and-pedro-martins).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have both `python 2.x` and `python 3.x` installed on your system.
When you do `pip install selenium`, the module gets installed for `python 2.x`.
To install the module for `python 3.x`, use `pip3 install selenium`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, man, but getting the result `Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\usuário\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (3.12.0)`